# Writing to file in project folder - Operation not permitted

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I use Json files for storing app-related objects.
Reading works but I'm confused about writing to the file.

```
private static void WriteFileContentsAsync(string content)
{
    var local = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); //(new Uri("Common/DataModel/EventsData.json", UriKind.Relative));
    var eventsFile = local.OpenFile("Common/DataModel/EventsData.json", FileMode.Open);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(eventsFile))
    {
        writer.WriteAsync(content);
    }
}
```

I can't open the file located in my project -> Common/DataModel/EventsData.json
The exception tells me that the operation is not permitted.

This is how I read from the same file:

```
private static string ReadFileContents()
{
    var ResrouceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Common/DataModel/EventsData.json", UriKind.Relative));
    if (ResrouceStream != null)
    {
        using (Stream myFileStream = ResrouceStream.Stream)
        {
            if (myFileStream.CanRead)
            {
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myFileStream);
                return myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

But `myFileStream.CanWrite` is false.

What would be the correct alternative?

**EDIT**

I tried this another way, but the file it should write to doesn't change and no errors occur:

```
private static void WriteFileContentsAsync(string content)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("Common/DataModel/EventsData.json",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Write);

    if (fs.CanWrite)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            writer.WriteAsync(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might open your own stream and then use RessourceWriter               FileStream fs = new FileStream("items.resources",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write);
IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter(fs);

Comment: ResourceWriter is not available, should I include something? MSDN states that it should be included in `System.Resources`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoFile;
isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

// Open or create a writable file.
IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
    new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Common/DataModel/EventsData.json",
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
    FileAccess.Write,
    isoFile);

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream);
```

Comment: Nope, It gives me the same exception `Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream`.

Comment: But does the user have permission? For example if you're running inside IIS the user of the Application-Pool needs write-permission...

Comment: I guess I'll have to look into that... is it wise to allow a user inside my project folders?

Comment: I'm very confused right now. Maybe you could provide a good starting link for me? I didn't even know that Windows Phone used IIS. The resource I'm trying to locate resides inside the project (on the phone itself).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as you can see. I'm not an expert yet.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be good content for one of those "I can't be the only one" memes!

I was constantly checking my project folder to see if the file has changed but I should have checked the install folder (somewhere in C:\data...). Writing does actually work :/

Hopefully, these examples and this answer will help many by-passers.